# SQL subqueries alternative to INTERSECT

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, intersect

I have two tables:
`P` and `PC` (master/detail joined by the column Id)

```
Table P:
Id integer
Name varchar(12)

Table PC:
Id   integer
Code varchar(12)
Val  number
```

I want to get all Names from P that satisfy the following simultaneous conditions:

- have a PC with `PC.Code='A'` and `Val>100`
- have another PC with  `PC.Code='B'` and `Val>80`

In summary, I'm only interested in those P.Name where the details comply with both conditions. Is there a way to select without resorting to INTERSECT?

The INTERSECT query is:

```
Select P.Name 
  from P, PC
 where P.Id=PC.Id
   and PC.Code='A' and Val>100
INTERSECT
Select P.Name 
  from P, PC
 where P.Id=PC.Id
   and PC.Code='B' and Val>80
```

(The interest is to check performance and also to allow the query to be run in Access)

Comment: [This article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302873/sql-syntax-error-with-intersect) shows you how to generically rewrite INTERSECT queries with JOINs. Specifically, see Vinko Vrsalovic's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not know how the performance is .. try it ..

```
SELECT P.Name 
  FROM P
  INNER JOIN PC AS a ON P.Id=a.Id and a.Cod='A' and a.Val>100
  INNER JOIN PC AS b ON P.Id=b.Id and a.Cod='B' and a.Val>80
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that is relationally equivalent (i.e. eliminating duplicate rows):

```
SELECT P.Name 
  FROM P
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM PC
                WHERE P.Id = PC.Id
                      AND PC.Code ='A' 
                      AND PC.Val > 100
              )
      AND EXISTS (
                  SELECT * 
                    FROM PC
                   WHERE P.Id = PC.Id
                         AND PC.Code ='B' 
                         AND PC.Val > 80
                 );
```

Here are a couple of alternatives that are semantically equivalent (in that they may return duplicate rows):

```
SELECT P.Name 
  FROM P, PC
 WHERE P.Id = PC.Id
       AND PC.Code ='A' 
       AND PC.Val > 100
       AND P.Name IN (
                      SELECT P1.Name 
                        FROM P AS P1, PC AS PC1
                       WHERE P1.Id = PC1.Id
                         AND PC1.Code = 'B' 
                             AND PC1.Val > 80
                     );
SELECT P.Name 
  FROM P, PC
 WHERE P.Id = PC.Id
       AND PC.Code ='A' 
       AND PC.Val > 100
       AND P.Name = ANY (
                         SELECT P1.Name 
                           FROM P AS P1, PC AS PC1
                          WHERE P1.Id = PC1.Id
                            AND PC1.Code = 'B' 
                                AND PC1.Val > 80
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Name
  FROM P
  JOIN PC AS P1 ON P.Id = P1.Id AND P1.Cod = 'A' AND P1.Val > 100
  JOIN PC AS P2 ON P.Id = P2.Id AND P2.Cod = 'B' AND P2.Val >  80
```

Using table aliases P1 and P2 allows you to do a 3-way join.  It isn't quite a self-join, though; not this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.Name
from P p
inner join PC pc1 on p.Id = pc1.Id and pc1.Cod = 'A' and pc1.Val > 100
inner join PC pc2 on p.Id = pc2.Id and pc2.Cod = 'B' and pc2.Val > 80
```

Comment: Nope, this won't work, since PC.Cod cannot simultaneously be both 'A' and 'B'.  You need a second join.

Comment: Cool, I'll upvote you to cancel out whoever it was that downvoted... :)

Comment: You can click again on the downvote and it goes back to normal :P thanks for the warning!

Comment: I would do that, except that I didn't downvote you to start with!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select P.Name 
  from P, PC
 where P.Id=PC.Id
   and PC.Cod='A' and Val>100
   and exists (Select 1 From PC Where Id = P.Id and Cod = 'B' and Val > 80)
```

Comment: Did you test this in Access? The reason I ask is that `Val` and `Name` are reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't actually use this but an alternative...

```
SELECT P.Name
FROM   P
       JOIN PC
         ON P.Id = PC.Id
WHERE  PC.Cod IN ( 'A', 'B' )
       AND Val > 80
GROUP  BY P.Id,
          P.Name
 HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN PC.Cod='A' and Val>100 THEN 1 END) = 1 
 AND MAX(CASE WHEN PC.Cod='B' and Val>80 THEN 1 END) = 1
```

Or for Microsoft Access the having clause would need to be

```
 HAVING MAX(IIf(PC.Cod='A' and Val>100, 1, 0)) = 1 
 AND MAX(IIf(PC.Cod='B' and Val>80, 1, 0)) = 1
```

Comment: Not by down-vote, but incredibly contorted.  It would work, but hardly a direct translation of the requirements.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - The OP asked for alternatives. This does one pass through the table.