# I was trying to intersect to table but it throws an error that 'intersect' is not valid at this position expecting EOF, ';'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id
     , name
     , bonus 
  FROM table1 a
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id = b.employee_id
intersect
SELECT id
     , name
     , bonus 
  FROM table1 a
 RIGHT 
  JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id = b.employee_id;
```

Comment: INTERSECT not exists in MySQL. Use WHERE EXISTS or INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: Check out this one https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/ and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302873/sql-syntax-error-with-intersect

Comment: And if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Mysql does not yet support intersect, though mariadb does

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tab1.id,tab1.name,tab1.bonus (SELECT id
     , name
     , bonus 
  FROM table1 a
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id = b.employee_id) as tab1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id
     , name
     , bonus 
  FROM table1 a
 RIGHT 
  JOIN table2 b
    ON a.id = b.employee_id) as tab2 ON tab1.id=tab2.id;
```

You can try like this